# Making a transparent layout which is added to another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a view to a layout which occupies a part of my screen. To this layout I want to add another layout which will be transparent. On this layout there should be only two lines which will scroll over the background layout. This I am doing so that my background layout is not invalidated and only the foreground is invalidated.

How can I add another layout which will be transparent?

Comment: Post your code.What kind if layout you are using linear or relative or frame... For Transpatent layout background you can use   yourLayoutobject.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Please put your xml code so we can help you proper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FrameLayout` as a parent layout and stack it up with as many layouts as you want. Thats one part of the answer. To make a layer (a layout in this case) transparent, set the alpha value in its background (a color) to 0. For instance `android:background="#00777777"` sets a background which is translucent with a dull gray.

You get the idea.

Comment: What if the parent isn't frameLayout originally?  Say it was linearLayout, but I want this overlay to work on all types of layouts, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use fram layout, which will allow you to add two views on each other.